# Saving customized STYLES when upgrading from ArcMap 10.2 to 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, arcgis-10.4, style-manager

In previous upgrades I have lost my personal styles used to create our atlas, and other labelling functions. Any suggestions how I can save these out and reinstall when we upgrade to Arcmap 10.4?

Answer (score 2):

Your styles are going to be stored in a `.style` file in a directory similar to this:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.X\ArcMap`

So what you will want to do is go there and find your `<username>.style` file and copy it somewhere like your desktop.  Then, after you upgrade you can replace the style file in the newly created directory for 10.4 installation with your original style file.